# PHP page updating only after 30 seconds

Tags: php, sleep

I'm sorry for the badly written question, but I'm new in PHP and I really don't know how to ask this in few words (cause I don't know what the exact problem is). "Similar Questions" didn't help and my searches only lead me to "how to increase max_execution_time" posts, more or less.
So, I'll just jump straight to my example:

```
<?php
    $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo $ipAddress;
?>
```

**The problem**:

If I load the page from PC A it outputs on the screen IP_a (great). But if I then load the page from PC B (different IP, different network) then it still outputs IP_a (??). ***But***, after 30 seconds of PC A loading the page if I (re)load the page from PC B it will print IP_b correctly. Of course, if I now (re)load the page from PC A it will print IP_b and only after 30 seconds of waiting I can(re)load the page to display IP_a.

A similar example is a php script that is just printing a random number. Running it in localhost (WAMP server), with every reload it prints a new random number, but running it as a page on the server it only prints a new random number only after 30 seconds after every reload. It's like, for 30 seconds after every (re)load the script is sleeping.

So, what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like you might have some caching proxy or something in front of the site/script. You should talk to the server admin.

Comment: As already mentioned, your server may be using a caching solution like Varnish. You can generate a `Cache-Control` and/or `Pragma` HTTP headers to instruct the proxy to not share the page, but PHP default settings should be good enough. Perhaps the proxy has a bit too aggressive settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It would seem the problem is indeed with the server provider. I talked with them.